# Round to nearest multiple of a number

Tags: c++, math

Is there an idiomatic way to round to the **nearest** multiple of a number, short of rounding both up and down and seeing which one is closest?

Assume only integers:

```
number   multiple   result
12       5          10
13       5          15
149      10         150
```

Comment: If you can round down (floor) to the nearest multiple, just add `multiple/2` to the input and now you have a round function. If you want it to round up in the odd cases, add `ceil(multiple/2)` instead.

Comment: @VoidStar I don't want to round up or down.

Comment: You have to pick a tie-breaker policy though. How do you round 15 with 6 as the multiple? You either go down or up. I gave you a way to do both. The answers below show only rounding down in this case since they pick the `multiple/2` option. Although some even prefer bankers rounding.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Add half of the multiple, then round down.

```
result = ((number + multiple/2) / multiple) * multiple;
```

or

```
result = number + multiple/2;
result -= result % multiple;
```

This rounds up if the number is exactly in the middle. You might need to tweak the calculation if you want different behaviour in that case. Also, beware overflow if `number` might be near the top of the type's range.

Comment: Hi, I think it's worth to notice that it may not work properly for negative numbers. I used a workaround like this:
```result = abs(number) + multiple/2;
result -= result % multiple;
result *= number > 0 ? 1 : -1;
```
I'm wondering if there's a better way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Easy Java Solution:

```
public Long roundToNearestLong(Long number, Long multiple) {
        if (number == null)
            return 0L;

        Long smallerMultiple = (number / multiple) * multiple;
        Long largerMultiple = smallerMultiple + multiple;

        // Return of closest of two
        return (number - smallerMultiple >= largerMultiple - number) ? largerMultiple : smallerMultiple;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I've answered this before on [Rounding off a number to the next nearest multiple of 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110606/rounding-off-a-number-to-the-next-nearest-multiple-of-5/)

With using `cmath::abs`

```
int rounded = n + abs((n % denom) - denom);
```

You can change `denom` with any denomination you want