# Rounding off a positive number to the next nearest multiple of 5

Tags: c++

I need to round of a number (the input is guaranteed to be an integer & is positive) to the next multiple of 5.

I tried this:

```
int round = ((grades[j] + 2)/5) * 5;
```

However, this rounds off the number to the nearest multiple of 5.

***Eg: 67 is rounded off to 65, not 70.***

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To round up the general form should be:

```
((n + denominator -1) / denominator )* denominator
```

so in your case:

```
int round = ((grades[j] + 4)/5) * 5;
```

The reason we deduct 1 from the denominator is to handle exact multiples of the rounding value for instance:

```
((70 + 4) / 5) * 5
```

would yield `70`

Comment: Why does this have so many upvotes when its wrong?  ((70 + 4) / 5) * 5 = 74.  Not a rounding fix and definitely not "70".

Comment: @Nimrod5000 you do realize this is an `int`, right? `(70 + 4) / 5)` would yield `14`. Then multiply by `5` which equals to `70`. Use some print statements and you will see.

Answer (score 9):

You can take the difference between `grades[j]` and the next number, and just add it. For example, if `grades[j] == 12` then `12 mod 5 == 2`, so add `5 - 2`.

Here is a sample program to test it out:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int x[] = {2,7,123,32}; // some random numbers to show how this works
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; {
        std::cout << x[i] << "\t" << x[i] + ((5-(x[i] % 5)) % 5) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2   5
7   10
123 125
32  35
```

Answer (score 5):

```
int mod = grades[j] % 5;
int round = grades[j] - mod;
if (mod > 0) {
    round += 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution using `cmath::abs`

```
int rounded = n + abs((n % denom) - denom);
```

You can change the `denom` with any other denomination you want

Comment: if your denom and number are say 2, this will produce 4.  Not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int num = grades[j] % 5 < 3 ? grades[j] - (grades[j] % 5) : grades[j] - (grades[j] % 5) + 5;
```

Here demo code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    //code
    int grades[5] = {10, 68, 12, 67, 41};
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        int num = grades[j] % 5 < 3? grades[j] - (grades[j] % 5) : grades[j] - (grades[j] % 5) + 5;
        printf("%d\n",num);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
10
70
10
65
40
```

I hope help you.

Answer (score 0):

One algorithm that works is:

1. half the round value
2. get the remainder of number by dividing it with roundValue
3. get quotient of division (so that we can multiply with it in end)
4. comparing it with the half of round Value
5. **if it's greater than half it rounds to the nearest greater value**
6. **if it's less than half it rounds to the nearest smaller value**

In code:

```
     int round(int nearest , int number){
            int half = nearest / 2;
            int answer = 0;  
            int remainder = number% nearest ;
            int quotient = number/ nearest ;
            if(remainder > half ){
                answer =(quotient+1) * nearest ;
            }else{
                answer =quotient * nearest ;
            }
        return answer;
        }
```

Comment: thank u @TobySpeight for making me realise my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Why so much of complication.
Here is the code.
Have a look.

```
vector<int> gradingStudents(vector<int> grades) {
    int size = grades.size();
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(grades[i]>40)
        {
            if((grades[i]+2)%5==0)
            grades[i]=grades[i]+2;
            else if((grades[i]+1)%5==0)
            grades[i]=grades[i]+1;
        }
        else if(grades[i]>37&&grades[i]<40)
        grades[i]=40;
    }
return grades;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a function to round up:

```
def next(number, base):
    temp = round(number / base) * base
    return temp
```

you can use it for your case like this:

```
next(grade[j], 5)
```

and in function it will be:

```
temp = round(67 / 5) * 5
return temp #temp = 75
```

some case not using round but using ceil